# If i am converting a entity to a DTO where this conversion code should exist?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

If i am converting a entity to a DTO where this conversion methord should exist?

1. in a utility class
2. in same entity
3. in DTO

I usually put these in utility class, but thinking why should not i move this to entity or DTO.

Like object (here: DTO or entity) should know what and how operation can be done on it (here: conversion)

Comment: Note that it's typical practice to use a tool such as MapStruct, which creates the conversion code for you. In this case, of course, you get a separate mapper class. Note that the entity _definitely_ should not have knowledge of the DTO class, since the entity is at a "lower" or more inner layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick sketch. It could be more simple/complex but I've found it effective for most cases.

Framework layer (remote and cache) mappers implement a data layer interface and leverage generics. They are dependent on domain and data layers without dependency between framework layers themselves.

```kotlin
// .domain
class Doggy

// .data
interface Mapper<DomainModel, FrameworkModel> {
  fun toDomainModel(model: FrameworkModel): DomainModel
  fun toFrameworkModel(model: DomainModel): FrameworkModel
}

// .remote
class DoggyDto

class DoggyDtoMapper: Mapper<Doggy, DoggyDto> {
  override fun toDomainModel(model: DoggyDto): Doggy
  override fun toFrameworkModel(model: Doggy): DoggyDto
}

// .cache
class DoggyEntity

class DoggyEntityMapper: Mapper<Doggy, DoggyEntity> {
  override fun toDomainModel(model: DoggyEntity): Doggy
  override fun toFrameworkModel(model: Doggy): DoggyEntity
}
```